# Should the SE chatroom be phased out for an official Arqade Discord?

Tags: discussion, chat

Its a thought that I've had for a little while.

The SE Chatroom seems to have built up quite a technological debt like links not unfurling or a mobile app. And it does make sense. The chatrooms of SE date of probably a good 10 years back, when Chatrooms were quite a hassle to create and moderate (we are talking about IRC days)

But now, there is a good alternative: Discord. And we [already got one running](http://discord.gg/rZNYQrZXjM)

So here is the thought: Is it time to phase out the SE Chatroom and change to an external chatroom?

From what I see:

**The pros:**

- Discord comes with a Mobile app
- I do think that people would have less of a mental block to join a discord than join a random chatroom

**The cons**

- No clue if SE will be ok with the idea
- Some functionality, like Questions unfurling and starring would be lost.
- I do not know the moderating tools we currently have on the current SE Chatroom, but I would think that the control might be lesser in something external.

So, what do you guys think?

Comment: Personally I think discord is awesome, but I doubt this will happen. SE has designed relatively intricate moderation tools for their sites including chat, and Discord would be much more removed from that.  The rep requirement for chat would also go out the window.  Bet new users would be more likely to join though.

Comment: Wonder how complex it would be to setup a bot that could link your SE account to your discord account, so it can give a role (and access to the deeper rooms) depending on what rep you got on the site

Comment: The lack of stars isn't really a bad thing, considering you can react to discord messages in relatively the same way. Bots for Discord chats are relatively advanced as well, and ones that post about new videos or twitch streams going live could probably easily post new questions ala Lazers.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I really wonder what those tools are because I don't think I've ever seen the result of them being used. Except the thing were you need a minimum or rep to use the chat.

Comment: Also I just realised, imagine just landing on the front page of Arqade for the first time. There is literally 0 mention of the chat, except for a link in the footer. Maybe we should push the chat a little more too? Like an ad in the sidebar or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.** Stack Exchange  already has some concerns around the Discord channel as it is, and so they would not support us making an official migration to an off-site chat.

Additionally, not everyone has Discord, and we can't really expect users who are just popping into chat asking for some help on Arqade to join a Discord server.

Everyone is welcome to use the Discord server to chat of course, while the server is usually quiet there's often a few folks lurking, but I can't see us doing an official migration.

Comment: Well that does settle it pretty hard. But I should open a new post. Should we, and how, could we push user to join us in chat? Right now there is not much places that show you we have a chat room, I think there is only the little link in the footer.

Comment: As a little note of additional context, the primary intent behind the Discord is to enable voice communications for group activities without needing to rely on someone's own personal Mumble server like we did way back in the day.

Comment: @Unionhawk teamspeakkkkkkk